# How to call a certain item in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

A full version of my code:

```
class Births:
    def __init__(self, year = 1990, number_of_births = 0):
        self.year = year
        self.number_of_births = number_of_births
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Births: {self.number_of_births} ({self.year})'
    
class Deaths:
    def __init__(self, year = 1990, number_of_deaths = 0):
        self.year = year
        self.number_of_deaths = number_of_deaths
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Deaths: {self.number_of_deaths} ({self.year})'
    
class Region:
    def __init__(self, name = 'Unknown', land_area = 1):
        self.name = name
        self.land_area = land_area
        self.births_list = []
        self.deaths_list = []
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} ({self.land_area} km^2)'
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Region):
            return False
        return self.name == other.name
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.name < other.name:
            return True
        return False
    
    def add_birth_record(self, birth_record):
        self.births_list.append(birth_record)
        
    
    def add_death_record(self, death_record):
        self.deaths_list.append(death_record)
        
    
    def get_number_of_births(self, start_year, end_year):
        sum = 0
        for births_number in self.births_list:
            if births_number in range(start_year, end_year):
                sum += Region.add_birth_record
        return sum
            
    

region1 = Region("Bay of Plenty", 12072)
birth1 = Births(2018, 3969)
birth2 = Births(2019, 4047)
death1 = Deaths(2018, 2583)
death2 = Deaths(2019 ,2787)
region1.add_birth_record(birth1)
region1.add_birth_record(birth2)
print(region1.get_number_of_births(2018, 2018))
print(region1.get_number_of_births(2018, 2019))
print(region1.get_number_of_births(2018, 2020))
print(region1.get_number_of_births(2020, 2020))
```

In the method def get_number_of_birth(self, start_year, end_year). I need to check if the numbers that I pass in for both start_year and end_year are in the range of whatever the print statements are calling (e.g. print(region1.get_number_of_births(2018, 2018)). If it is, then the method would calculates and returns the number of births in the region within the specified time period (inclusive). However, I failed to access the items (2018) and (2019) and don't know how to compare those two values.

So what do I need to do to fix this problem?

Hope someone can help, thanks!

Comment: That isn't valid Python code.  Please show us what you actually have.

Comment: Your definition of `a` above makes no sense.  Is it a list of two elements?  Is each element a string or what?  There is no such thing is Python as `3969 (2018)`

Comment: My code has been updated @FrankYellin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use year variable to get and Number directly.

```
class Births:
    def __init__(self, year=1990, number_of_births=0):
        self.year = year
        self.number_of_births = number_of_births

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Births: {self.number_of_births} ({self.year})'

class Deaths:
    def __init__(self, year=1990, number_of_deaths=0):
        self.year = year
        self.number_of_deaths = number_of_deaths

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Deaths: {self.number_of_deaths} ({self.year})'

class Region:
    def __init__(self, name='Unknown', land_area=1):
        self.name = name
        self.land_area = land_area
        self.births_list = []
        self.deaths_list = []

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} ({self.land_area} km^2)'

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Region):
            return False
        return self.name == other.name

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.name < other.name:
            return True
        return False

    def add_birth_record(self, birth_record):
        self.births_list.append(birth_record)

    def add_death_record(self, death_record):
        self.deaths_list.append(death_record)

    def get_number_of_births(self, start_year, end_year):
        end_year = end_year + 1
        sum = 0
        for births_number in self.births_list:
            if births_number.year in range(start_year, end_year):
                sum += births_number.number_of_births
        return sum


region1 = Region("Bay of Plenty", 12072)
birth1 = Births(2018, 3969)
birth2 = Births(2019, 4047)
death1 = Deaths(2018, 2583)
death2 = Deaths(2019, 2787)
region1.add_birth_record(birth1)
region1.add_birth_record(birth2)
print(region1.get_number_of_births(2018, 2018))
print(region1.get_number_of_births(2018, 2019))
print(region1.get_number_of_births(2018, 2020))
print(region1.get_number_of_births(2020, 2020))
```

```
3969
8016
8016
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Also you can't use range with same start and stop, because last element of range doesn't add to the list, so I add
`end_year = end_year + 1`
to make range works like you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store 2018 and 2019 as tuples, you have to add a comma after them:

```py
a = [(2018,), (2019,)]
a[0][0]
```

```
>>> 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

I appended tuples that has the year and number of births so they could easily be called in the later function:

```
def add_birth_record(self, birth_record:"Births"):
    self.births_list.append((birth_record.year, birth_record.number_of_births))
def get_number_of_births(self, start_year, end_year):
    sum = 0
    for item in self.births_list:
        if item[0] in range(start_year, end_year):
            sum += item[1]
    return sum
```

for the following output:

```
0
3969
8016
0
```

Hope this helped!